# conjugation of なんとかならん

Tags: words, conjugations, sentence

i was wondering about this conjugation[ 何とかならん] of the expression なんとかならん i don't know why it was conjugated like this

戸塚のためにも 何とかならんもんかね

Answer (score 1):

This is an informal version of なんとかならない, i.e. なんとか+ならない, the negative of 何とかなる ('to be able to manage somehow or another'). In some Japanese dialects (such as Kansai), the negative inflexion 'anai' is sometimes contracted to 'an'. For example, わからない - わからん, しらない-しらん, ならない-ならん, etc.